# How much admin does running a PostgreSQL server in Production require?

Tags: postgresql

I'm setting up a website and am considering PostgreSQL for the DB. But I really just want to set it up and forget about it. How likely is this "set and forget" mindset for PostgreSQL? If it's not realistic, what kind of maintenance tasks should I expect to be carrying out?

edit: I found useful info here: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/maintenance.html

Comment: That depends entirely on what you are going to use it for.

Comment: Me too I want to use a car and never refuel it... Oil change - eww

Answer (score 5):

"Set it and forget it" shouldn't be the attitude for **any** production system.

That being said, it's no worse then any other major player like MySQL, MSSQL, etc.

Comment: Thanks, but I was looking for what kind of tasks I can expect to carry out on a regular basis as well?

Comment: @jason.ppdev there's no way anyone can answer that with the scant details that you provided.

Answer (score 1):

Backups of course.

Apart from that it depends on how reliable it has to be and how much performance you need. As long as you don't have special requirements on reliability and do not get very many hits it will run fine. It does automatic maintenance (auto vacuum) like removing dead tuples and analysing data to update the statistics used by the query planner.

However when the load rises you might have to tweak the parameters controlling auto vacuum. Also when performance drops you will have to start tweaking other parameters and monitor performance.

Personally I found the following book very informative [PostgreSQL 9.0 High Performance](http://www.packtpub.com/postgresql-90-high-performance/book). It discusses things like which hardware to get, which filesystem to use and how to tune postgresql it self.